# How to use browser variable defined in page factory is used in hook file

Tags: java, selenium, hook, page-factory

I am using cucumber with POM.I have created a file called "Driver factory" where i have initialised a String browserName as a parameter to public static void openBrowser(String browserName). (Because i want to test in multiple browser).I am trying to call method in hooks file df.openBrowser(browserName);

```
public static void openBrowser(String browserName) throws Exception{
          if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
              System.out.println("***Test cases are executing in Chrome****");
              System.setProperty("webdriver.webdriver.chrome.driver.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
              driver=new ChromeDriver();
              driver.manage().window().maximize();
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          }
```

I am getting error in Hooks.java file saying "browserName cannot be resolved to a variable".

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please add the code to your question, not the comments. There is an icon in the question editor that allows you to easily format the code as well.

Comment: What line is the error on? From your description, it sounds like the error is coming from a file other than the code you have posted. You should run your code in debug mode (see your IDE's docs on how to do this) and step through your code until you run across the error. This error typically is the result of using a variable without declaring it. In Hooks.java when you called `df.openBrowser(browserName);`, did you define `browserName` before that line?

Comment: Yes you are right the error is coming from hooks.java.I wrote method - public static void openBrowser(String browserName) in DriverFactory.java and same function I am calling in hooks.java.Even though if i initialise browserName in hooks.java i m getting error